# Is there any way in os x to configure apps to put their temp files on the external drive?

Tags: macos, mac, adobe-photoshop

I want to save my SSD from unnecessary write-cycles.
Is there a way to configure OS X applications to put temp files to the specified directory on the external drive? I have this question primary about Xcode Unity3d and Photoshop. Is there any general option to configure cache\temporary data location for all applications?
I have ssd-only mac, so I can use only external drive as additional one.

Comment: The question will be, what happens when your external drive is not connected?

Comment: In this case I can change location for temp files/cache.
I know that there is such option in opera browser - to change cache directory.
I wonder is it possible for other apps, especially for Xcode, Photoshop and Unity3d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But why? Storing temp/cache files there would make it unefficient (since it's SSD, the apps would work slower on an external hard-drive) and/or potentially unsafe.

You can, though, create a symlink to the external drive.
Something like that in Terminal, for example with your user's "Downloads" folder:

This command removes the original directory. Careful with that and check the path thoroughly.

rm -rf ~/Downloads/

You could need to add "sudo" command at the beginning, though, if you haven't got enough user permissions to that folder; and in case of ~/Downloads/ you don't need it since it's located in your home directory.
If the path contains spaces, put the path in the quotes.

Tis one creates the replacement directory on an external hard drive (replace "MyWD" with your HDD name) or create it in Finder itself.

```
mkdir /Volumes/MyWD/Downloads/
```

And this one replaces it with a symlink to the directory on the external drive

```
ln -s /Volumes/MyWD/Downloads/ ~/Downloads
```

Also, SSDs are replaceable even on the latest Macbooks, you can easily buy and replace the original SSD with a third-party one if the original SSD will go worn. You can also consider AppleCare which would extend your warranty if you fear about SSD failures.

But I'd keep temporary and cache files on SSD since it makes everything work faster.

**Update** (to answer your comment):

If external HDD was switched off, you won't be able to access the files by its original path. If you want to put the files back to their original places, you should remove the symlink by entering the command:

```
rm ~/Downloads
```

(it removes the symlink to the directory on the external HDD)

Then you should re-create the plain directory (feel free to do it in Finder):

```
mkdir ~/Downloads
```

Then you can move (or copy) the content of that folder from the external HDD.

Comment: Thank you very much.
How to return back? If external HDD is switched off?
To set directories to their previous locations on native drive?

Comment: @Eugene I updated the answer to answer it.